# How to replace quotation mark with Guillemet

Tags: regex, ms-word, wildcard

I want to convert quotation marks to Guillemet using Microsot Word wildcards or Regex.
**Example**

*Before*

> "Quotation marks", also called "quotes", "quote marks", quotemarks,
>   speech marks, inverted commas or talking marks

*After*

> «Quotation marks», also called «quotes», «quote marks», quotemarks,
>   speech marks, inverted commas or talking marks

Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex for matching text and quotation marks:

```
"(.*?)"
```

Then you can replace using group 1 (usually `$1` depending what you are using), and surrounding by guillemets.

See [this in action](https://regex101.com/r/lzDpJz/1).

*A note about the regex:* I am using `*?` quantifier (or *lazy quantifier*) which matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed.

Comment: @KillerDeath sadly I do neither have Word nor know how it works. But since asked for wildcard **or** regex, I gave the regex!

Comment: I see but Word can't use regexes in a normal way as Sublime, Notepad++ etc. It's better you don't have it.